# Hpricot: how to do conditional search using Hpricot in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hpricot

I am parsing two different sites having similar HTML tags. I need to use a common parser for this. My issue is one site has a HTML format div/ol/li/span/a and other has div/ol/li/h3/a

My current parser code is

```
 doc = Hpricot(open("http://test.com").read)
 doc.search("div/ol/li/span/a").each do |a|
   question = a.inner_html
   ans_url =  a.attributes['href']
   puts question
   puts answer_url
 end
```

This works well with the first site. How can I use this same code to parse my second site(div/ol/li/h3/a). How can I specify conditions. What I tried is shown below

```
 doc = Hpricot(open("http://test.com").read)
 doc.search("div/ol/li/span or h3/a").each do |a|
   question = a.inner_html
   ans_url =  a.attributes['href']
   puts question
   puts answer_url
 end
```

But this didnot work. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked I used the below code

```
 doc.search("div/ol/li/span/a | div/ol/li/h3/a").each do |a|
  #..
 end
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Why not just search for both?

Edit: I was wrong again--and I realized why I switched to [Nokogiri](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/). It's much easier to use:

```
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://example.com/'))


doc.search("div > ol > li > span > a", "div > ol > li > h3 > a").each do |a|
  question = a.content
  answer_url =  a.attr('href').value
  puts question
  puts answer_url
end
```

Comment: I used your answer, but its showing wrong number of arguments (2 for 1). Please help.

Comment: Thanks dude. when I changed it I get full html content of the page, when I puts a.inner_html and also i get an 'attribute' error when I used a.attributes['href']. If use '|' for 'or' am getting the desired result are '|' and 'or' same.

Comment: Thanks dude. Your solution really helped me get out of this crap. thanks a lot :)